# Confirmation box not working on a link to another tab

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tabs, confirmation

heres the code of my link confirmation to another tab:

```
<a href="linksite" onclick="linktab()" target="_tab">Go to link</a>

 <script type'text/javascript'>
       function linktab()
       {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to go to the link?');
       };
       </script>
```

i think the problem is the Target=TAB but i dont know how would i do that without closing the other site for loading purposes.

Comment: another tab in browser?

Comment: @arun yes tab on another browser,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `onload="linktab()"` use `onclick="return linktab()`

Comment: oh my bad, it was on "onclick".. xD i mistyped

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `onclick`, not `onload`.

You also must make sure that your `onclick` *itself* returns the value returned from the function:

```
 onclick="return linktab()"
```

Otherwise your `onclick` will just invoke a function, but disregard what it returns.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/72bVp/)

Note that valid values for `target` are[*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html):

> - Any string, with the following restrictions:
>
>   - must not start with a `"_"` character
>   - must be at least one character long
> - any case-insensitive match for one of the following literal strings: `"_blank"`, `"_self"`, `"_parent"`, or `"_top"`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove  `target='_tab'` and in the confirmation you can do

```
if(confirm('sure?')){var win=window.open(url, '_blank');win.focus();}
```

You can study more from this question, very interesting! [open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)